# Juju deployment fails due to "container failed to start" error

Tags: juju, lxc

I had tried to deploy mysql and i had this error:

> agent-state-info: container failed to start

Outputs from log as following:

```
Line 47: machine-0: 2014-08-14 02:02:30 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:250 error dialing "wss://localhost:17070/": websocket.Dial wss://localhost:17070/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:17070: connection refused
Line 48: machine-0: 2014-08-14 02:02:30 ERROR juju.worker runner.go:218 exited "api": unable to connect to "wss://localhost:17070/"
ERROR juju.container.lxc lxc.go:243 container failed to start: container failed to start
Line 438: machine-0: 2014-08-14 02:04:44 ERROR juju.provisioner provisioner_task.go:421 cannot start instance for machine "1": container failed to start
```

How do I resolved this issue?

Any inputs are greatly appreciate.

Comment: I notice that only trusty charms are able to work. All other charms running on precise was not able to deploy. Anyone can confirm this? I am running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is this with the local provider?  Also, can you give the commands you used?

Comment: yes i tried deploying with the local lxc.
juju deploy owncloud --show-log --debug

Comment: Close voters: How is this not reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Trusty Charms only work on Trusty systems (Ubuntu 14.04). Precise Charms only work on Precise systems (Ubuntu 12.04). You're using LXC as provider on a 14.04 machine. Because LXC isn't complete virtualisation, LXC will not be able to create a precise machine on a Trusty host. This is the error you are getting. Juju tries to provision a new precise machine, but it fails, because **it can only make Trusty machines on a Trusty host.**

**You can specify the series in the deploy command.** The following command will deploy the `trusty` version of mysql.

```
juju deploy cs:trusty/mysql
```

If you don't specify which series (OS version), Juju uses the default-series. The default-series can be specified in environments.yaml for a new environment:

```
default-series: trusty
```

Or use the following command to change the default-series of an existing, already bootstrapped environment:

```
juju set-env "default-series=trusty"
```

[source](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-deploying.html#deploying-from-the-charm-store)